# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

Tags: ios, arrays

I am getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***

I am not getting where is exact issue please help me on this

```
- (NSMutableArray*) arrayAtPointIndex:(NSInteger) index {
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if ( series )
    {
        for (int plotIndex = 0; plotIndex <= [_points count]; plotIndex++) {
            SALChartCoordinate * coord1 = [_points objectAtIndex:plotIndex];
            CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:index] floatValue] );
            [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:differ]];
        }

    }
    if ( [array count] > 0 )
        return [array autorelease];

    [array release];
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Why `int plotIndex = 1` and not `int plotIndex = 0`?

Comment: you have  only 5 values index 0 to 4, you tried to access 5th.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I don't see *where* though; do you?

Comment: Some code seems to be missing.

Comment: once check your coord1.series array app getting crashed because of coord1.series array.

Comment: What is `coord1.series` and are you sure that you want to access `[coord1.series objectAtIndex:plotIndex]` with the same index `plotIndex` ?

Comment: may be _points can't fetch objectAtIndex:plotIndex. it may be blank or less item then plotIndex

Comment: @Martin put your comment in an answer!

Comment: @Zaph: It is already said in the (updated) answer of CRDave. No need for another one.

Comment: So probably the `index` parameter is out of range for the array `coord1.series`. It should be easy to check that in the debugger ...

Comment: @Nishi - the exception is quite clear - `coord1.series` does not have as many elements as you're asking it for. If it has 5 items, you can only ask for items at indexes 0 through 4. I think you need to provide more information concerning the contents of these arrays, and perhaps what is calling your `arrayAtPointIndex:` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most possible place is : `[coord1.series objectAtIndex:index]`

Because you are not checking that NSArray series size and plotIndex.

put some condition like this

```
if(coord1.series.count-1 <= index)
{
     CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:plotIndex] floatValue] );
     [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:differ]];
}
```

**NOTE**: You are accessing array and inner array with same index. It can not be said for sure  but this is indicating some logic problem. So check for that.

Comment: This would eliminate the bounds/range exception, but would mask the underlying problem, unless you also logged an issue when your `if` condition is not met. It seems the `coord1.series` is expected to have the same number of items as `_points`

Comment: for (int plotIndex = 0; plotIndex < [_points count]; plotIndex++) {
            SALChartCoordinate * coord1 = [_points objectAtIndex:plotIndex];
            CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:index] floatValue] );
            [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:differ]];
        } but on first call it is crashing when loop has been called

Comment: on which line u r talking?

Comment: CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:index] floatValue] ); my points count is 6 and wehre as series count is 5

Comment: Put this statement before you line : NSLog(@"series count:%d index:%d",coord1.series, index) And tell me what you are getting in consol log.

Comment: YEs that is problem count:5 means your array contain 5 object and index:5 it means you want to access 6th element of array which is not there. thats why it is giving error. (Remember array index start from 0 so index 5 means 6th element)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30256/discussion-between-nishi-and-crdave)

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes in Objective-C (and most programming languages) start at 0. So the first item in your 5-item list is at index 0, and the last item is at index 4.

Thus, your for loop should not start at 1, but rather:

```
for (int plotIndex = 0; plotIndex < [_points count]; plotIndex++) {
...
```

But, as `trojanfoe` correctly mentions, this is not the cause of the exception. Can you also print out or examine the value of:

`coord1.series`

As I imagine the number of items in the series is not the same as the number of points, though you seem to be relying on the fact that it is:

```
CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:plotIndex] floatValue] );
                                      ^ coord1.series does not have an item at this index
```

Thus, I think **your first course of action** is to determine whether it is safe to assume that `coord1.series` has the same (or greater) number of elements than `_points`, and if so, why it currently does not.

Comment: That's not causing the exception; it's just missing the first entry.

Comment: @trojanfoe You're correct. The loop start at 1 just jumped out so quickly, I made an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @Craig consider changing you answer so it emphasizes that `coord1.series` may have a different size than `_points`.

Answer (score 0):

check carefully..

```
if ( series )
    {
        for (int plotIndex = 1; plotIndex < [_points count]; plotIndex++) {
            SALChartCoordinate * coord1 = [_points objectAtIndex:plotIndex];//problem not here
            CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:plotIndex] floatValue] );//problem is here check your array which contains only five objects but you are trying to get 6th object that is the reason.
            [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:differ]];
        }

    }
```

Comment: yes problem is on second line only..but on first call only it is crashing

Comment: because you kept like index which is coming from called function ,so first time you are passing 5 in the place of index that's why this senario happend

Comment: skip that like if index value more than the coord1.series array count.

Answer (score -3):

```
 - (NSMutableArray*) arrayAtPointIndex:(NSInteger) index {
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ( series )
{
    for (int plotIndex = 0; plotIndex < [_points count]; plotIndex++) {
        SALChartCoordinate * coord1 = [_points objectAtIndex:plotIndex];
        CGFloat differ = abs( [[coord1.series objectAtIndex:plotIndex] floatValue] );
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:differ]];
    }

}
if ( [array count] > 0 )
    return [array autorelease];

[array release];
return nil;
```

}

try out this code...

Comment: OFFS, how many more times? That's not causing the exception; it's just missing the first entry.