# Uncaught exception: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 60 beyond bounds [0 .. 59]

Tags: iphone, arrays, exception

```
    NSLog(@"m_datasource %d and coord.color %d",[m_dataSource.colors count],[coord.colorIndexes count]);

            cell.spotColor  = [m_dataSource.colors objectAtIndex: [coord.colorIndexes lastObject] intValue];
```

Here the values which I am getting for 
m_datasource 60 and coord.color 2
How to resole this?

Comment: Uh, use a bigger array or a smaller index.  (Note that a common error is to forget that array indexes run 0..N-1 rather than 1..N.)

Comment: You had the *same problem* here today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648195/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsrangeexception-reason. I don't want to sound unfriendly, but did you understand the problem and solution?

Answer (score 2):

Is it due to the fact that your NSArray, which I assume you are using, starts at zero? and that the 60th object is at index 59?

Comment: NSLog(@"m_datasource %d and coord.color %d",[m_dataSource.colors count],[coord.colorIndexes count]);

            cell.spotColor  = [m_dataSource.colors objectAtIndex:( [coord.colorIndexes lastObject] intValue]-1);

Comment: Try that, it has a '-1' at the end. if that doesn't work send me all the code you have and i'll sort it

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using the count method and use the returned value to get an object at an index, then you have to minus 1 since an array of 2 objects has a count of 2, but object 1 has an index of 0 and object 2 has an index of 1.

`int index = [someArraytoCount count] - 1;`

`someObj *myObj = [otherArray objectAtIndex:index];`

Additionally be safe by using logic.

`if (index < [otherArray count] && index >= 0)`

Then that index will exist in the array and you won't have an app crash

Answer (score 0):

You're doint it wrongly:

```
NSLog(@"m_datasource %d and coord.color %d",[m_dataSource.colors count],[coord.colorIndexes count]);
cell.spotColor  = [m_dataSource.colors objectAtIndex: [coord.colorIndexes lastObject] intValue];
```

Above if your last object in `coord.colorIndexes` is "100" then check the statemnt - it will look like this:

```
cell.spotColor  = [m_dataSource.colors objectAtIndex: 100];
```

But in your `m_dataSource.colors` array contains only 60 objects, that's why it throws array out of index exception.

Replace your code with below snippet:

```
// get array count and substract with 1 - so it will retrun you last index of coord.colorIndexes array
cell.spotColor  = [m_dataSource.colors objectAtIndex: [coord.colorIndexes count]-1];
```

Hope this will help you brief about array concepts.